Why in IE Irodov the formula for energy of a system of electrical charges an additional factor of 1/2 is mentioned?

I think that it instead be something like W=sigma(qiVi)

Why do you think this? Please give your reasoning.

The factor of 1/2 is correct, but there’s a typo: $q_1$ is supposed to be $q_i$. Try it for two charges.

Wikipedia

See pages 94 to 97 where Irodov derives this equation. The factor of ¹⁄₂ is there because $\sum q_i\varphi_i$ counts each pairwise interaction twice.
